# How to generate image sprites in ember-cli using compass?

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js, compass-sass, broccolijs

*Update* - 20140614:

After not getting any answers to this question, or on github,
I decided to come up with my own solution to the problem.
I was using compass for a number of things,
but its main utility was in its ability to generated image sprites.
Most other things could be accomplished using pure SCSS.

Thus, I wrote [broccoli-sprite](https://github.com/bguiz/broccoli-sprite).
This, used in conjunction with ember-cli's built in support for SCSS
using [broccoli-sass](https://github.com/joliss/broccoli-sass),
was able to meet my needs.

[image: NPM]

You can [read more about the process here](http://blog.bguiz.com/post/88719320815/broccoli-sprite-released).

Now I am thus no longer interested in integrating compass into my ember-cli app.
As my solution does not directly answer the question (as it does not use compass),
I consider this question **to be unanswered**.
Since this question might yet benefit others in the community who wish to do so,
I am leaving this open, and will still honour the bounty!

*Update* - 20140620:

Bounty has expired.

---

*Original question*:

In an [ember-cli](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli) app,
using [broccoli-compass](https://github.com/g13013/broccoli-compass),
how can it be configured such that the generated CSS references image file paths correctly, including generated image file paths?

Using compass, the following SCSS:

```
@import"icon/*.png";
@include all-icon-sprites;
```

… will generate a single `.png` file with all of the images in the `icon` folder, and CSS for displaying each.

I would like to be able to do the same via compass within ember-cli,
which uses [broccoli](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli) 
to build its asset pipeline.

- Must work within ember-cli - that is, it must be built when ember serve or ember build is run
- Must use compass to generate image sprites from a folder of images
- The images generated should be copied to the assets folder
- The generated CSS should point to images located in the assets folder, not to a temporary tree folder

---

#### What I have attempted so far:

**#1**

```
app.styles = function() {
  var tree = this.appAndDependencies();
  return compileCompass(tree, {
    outputStyle: 'expanded',
    relativeAssets: false,
    sassDir: this.name+'/styles',
    imagesDir: 'public/images',
    // imagesDir: this.name+'/styles/images',
    cssDir: '/assets',
  });
};
```

When I do this, the `compass` command fails because it cannot locate the image files within the tree.

**#2**

```
app.styles = function() {
  var tree = this.appAndDependencies();
  return compileCompass(tree, {
    outputStyle: 'expanded',
    relativeAssets: false,
    sassDir: this.name+'/styles',
    // imagesDir: 'public/images',
    imagesDir: this.name+'/styles/images',
    cssDir: '/assets',
  });
};
```

Just to try things out, I copy the image files into the styles directory.
This time the compass command succeeds, but,
the generated CSS references image files that do not exist.
The generated images do not appear to get copied into the assets folder as expected (
or anywhere else for that matter):

```
$tree tmp/output
tmp/output/
├── assets
│   ├── app.css
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── qunit.css
│   ├── qunit.js
│   └── vendor.css
├── images
├── index.html
├── testem.js
└── tests
    └── index.html

3 directories, 8 files
```

---

*Details*:

SCSS that I would like to be able to compile (for sprite generation):

```
@import"compass/utilities/sprites";
$icon-layout: smart;
$icon-sprite-dimensions: true;
@import"icon/*.png";
@include all-icon-sprites;
@import"compass/css3/images";
```

---

Comment: If possible, it would be great if you could post your solution (by answering your own question) so others can see it more clearly and so the question appears answered :)

Comment: @markthethomas Thanks for your comment, unfortunately, however, the solution that I have gone with **does not** meet the requirements of this question. I found a way to create sprites, but not to use compass. See my update from 20140614: "As my solution does not directly answer the question (as it does not use compass), and this question might yet benefit others in the community who wish to do so, I am leaving this open, and will still honour the bounty!"... I still consider this question to be unanswered, and the solution is still at large!

Comment: What! 250, i answered this more than a week ago. Have some sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The hard way

Add to your `brocfile`

```
var app = new EmberApp({
    compassOptions: {
        imagesDir: 'public/assets'
    }
});
```

and then import the icons

```
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@import "icons/*.png";

$icons-sprite-dimensions: true;
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

and overwrite the path

```
.icons-sprite {
    background-image: url('/assets/icons-sea02d16a6c.png');
}
```

### The more elegant way

Configure compass to use particular directory

```
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@import "compass/configuration";

$compass-options: (http_path: "/", generated-images-path: "public/assets", http-generated-images-path: "/assets", images-path: "public/assets");

@include compass-configuration($compass-options);

@import "icons/*.png";
$icons-sprite-dimensions: true;
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

It is not a perfect solution although it works. Configuration should not be stored in `.scss` files. Unfortunately those options inside `brocfile` are not going to fly.

Answer (score 3):

I thought this would be solved by using an ember addon and postprocess hook, i published an addon,

To install run: `npm install ember-cli-compass --save-dev` inside your project.

Configure in your `Brocfile.js`.

```
/* global require, module */

var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

var app = new EmberApp({
    compass: {
        outputStyle: 'expanded',
        relativeAssets: false,
        sassDir: 'assets',
        imagesDir: 'images',
        cssDir: 'assets'
    }
});

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

This seems to do what you want but i am not sure. Also i needed to change `public/images` to just `images`, because `public/images` folder copies into `dist/images`. Maybe that's the issue and you don't need an addon.

I hope this fixs your problem.

Comment: Would you mind linking me to your git repository? Looks like [you have not added it to you package.json](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ember-cli-compass).

Comment: @bguiz fixed it now, i didn't add it because i am not sure if it works right.

Comment: @ facebook I'm sorry, but I have not been unable to get the time to verify this - has any one else tried this and got it to work?

Comment: @ facebook that is a little demanding isn't it? The bounty isn't awarded by me though, looks like you will have to ask [the user that is offering it](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2985029/xxx) to extend it. I would if I could, I'm just not having very much luck at the moment after having just upgraded my OS. See [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/503184/7593) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/503238/7593).

Comment: @ facebook that's harsh.